$3\times3$ real matrix decomposition to SVD using two unit quaternions and scale vector
I've been trying to search about doing $3\times3$ real matrix SVD, but instead of decomposing it into matrices, represent the two rotations as unit quaternions with the singular values as separate scale vector. I wonder if there's more straightforward approach to get the quaternions directly, instead of first doing SVD decomposition to rotation matrices and then figuring out quaternions from those?
Thanks for help in advance.

See this publication

Any comment about the reference I gave ?

@JeanMarie Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!
